# Binding dropdownlist to dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, sqlconnection

I'm filling a datatable from a stored procedure and then filling a dataset with my datatable but I'm getting  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line with ddl.DataSource = ds.

How can I solve my binding?

```
using (var scTyche = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KondorConnectionConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("DropDownListFolders1");
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var ds = new DataSet();

        scTyche.Open();
        var cmdTyche = scTyche.CreateCommand();
        cmdTyche.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdTyche.CommandText = "dbo.spGetFolders";
        cmdTyche.CommandTimeout = 60;
        cmdTyche.Parameters.Add("@nBranchId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intBranchId;

        da.SelectCommand = cmdTyche;
        da.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "strShort";
        ddl.DataValueField = "nId";
        ddl.DataBind();

        cmdTyche.Parameters.Clear();

        scTyche.Dispose();
        scTyche.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Either the table is not being added properly, or `ddl` is null.  Can you set a breakpoint at `var ddl = ...` and step over to see the value held in `ddl`?  This will help answer the question.

Comment: check if ds containing table having rows or not. you can try like this : if(ds.Tables[0].rows.count > 0)

Comment: @kumarch1 it is not possible for `ds` to be null as he has instantiated it with `new DataSet()`.  It *is possible* that it's empty, but that will not throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @kumarch1 again, (regarding your edit), that would not throw the exception the OP is asking about... it would simply display no lines in the DropDownList... the most likely cause of this is that `ddl` is null, thus trying to access it's `DataSource` property would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: The ddl was null I found out now

Answer (score 0):

I normally just fill the dataset from the adapter. The ds contains a table collection. Depending on how many result sets your stored proc returns, that will be reflect in the collection Tables[0], Tables[1] etc...
In your case, I am assuming it's it only returning 1. With this approach, you don't need the added DataTable variable.

Also, the dispose and close is kind of redundant since the using statement is exactly designed to handle this via the IDisposable interface.

```
// example
da.Fill(ds);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    ddl.Datasource = ds.Tables[0];
    // etc....
}
```